# Bubble sort program in c

Tags: c, bubble-sort

I wrote the following code for a bubble sort program in c:
http://pastebin.com/Jtcpn59U

However, the bubblesort function does not seem to be working. Once I enter the array values as prompted by the getArray() function the program goes idle. Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Comment: you can exit isordered early, namely on line `55` you can just do `return false`, and outside of the for loop do `return true`

Answer (score 4):

Pay attention to this part of program :

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
            if(a[i]>a[i+1])
            {
                           temp=a[i];
                           a[i]=a[i+1];
                           a[i+1]=temp;
            }
 }
```

When you are writing `if(a[i]>a[i+1])` , a[i+1] seeks for position that does not exists!
Just limit your for loop to less than n-1 :

```
for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
```

Instead of `for(i=0;i<n;i++)`

Hope, this will work! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 bool flag, i;
 flag=TRUE;
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
     if(a[i]>a[i+1])
     flag=FALSE;
 }
```

The `bool` type is large enough to store the values 0 or 1 but your are using your `i` object as an index variable.

Then in `bubbleSort`function:

```
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
     if(a[i]>a[i+1])
     {
         temp=a[i];
         a[i]=a[i+1];
         a[i+1]=temp;
     }
 }
```

When `i` is `n - 1` you are accessing `a[n - 1]` and `a[n]` but `a[n]` is outside your array. Remember arrays are `0`-origin: your last array element is `a[n - 1]`

Answer (score 1):

`bubbleSort()` itself has an illegal memory access since the loop variable `i` is from 0 to n-1, but you access `a[i+1]`.  but that would not cause it to sit idle.

the same issue occurs in `isordered()` and may cause it always to return `FALSE` - that could the cause of your unlimited recursion.

to fix the two issues above, reduce the loop limits to `n-1` wherever you access `i+1` inside the loop.  to see the error yourself, run with valgrind (ie if it is installed on your machine, do `valgrind a.out` replacing `a.out` with whatever your program is called).

`isordered()` should end with `return flag` instead of the silly tests.

ouah's point (that you are making the loop counter `bool` instead of `int`) is also valid.